# Use a double integral to find the area of the region inside the cardioid $r=1+\cos\theta$ and outside the circle $r=3\cos \theta$

Tags: calculus

I found their point of intersection ($\pi/3$ and $-\pi/3$) and integrated but got the answer wrong. (The answer is $\pi/4$).

Comment: You should show us your set up, and maybe we can tell you where you have made a mistake.  First thought, the area inside the cartiod and outside the cricle is to the right of the cricle i.e. $\theta \in [\frac {\pi}{3}, \frac {5\pi}{3}]$

Comment: My set up: https://i.imgur.com/xUomeGz.png

Comment: In polar co-ordinates, the area element is $\mathrm dx~\mathrm dy=r~\mathrm dr~\mathrm d\theta$

Comment: like this? https://i.imgur.com/NapjrzL.png

Comment: @user483926 your second answer is exactly what I got during my equation solving. I did the integrals 100% correctly, it seems like this is a trick question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a picture.

[image]

the green regions.

$\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{2} (1+\cos\theta)^2 - (3\cos\theta)^2 \ d\theta\\
\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{2} 1+2\cos\theta - 8\cos^2\theta\ d\theta\\
\cos^2\theta = \frac 12 + \frac 12\cos 2\theta\\
\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{2} -3 + 2\cos\theta - 4\cos2\theta\ d\theta\\
-3 + 2\sin\theta - 4\sin\theta\cos\theta|_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{2}\\
2-\frac {\pi}{2}$

the red regions.

$\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^{\pi} (1+\cos\theta)^2\ d\theta\\
\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^{\pi} \frac 32 +2\cos\theta + \frac 12\cos^2\theta\\
\frac {3\pi}{4} - 2$

And together they are $\frac \pi4$

Comment: didn't expect it to be tricky, thanks!

Comment: We have to treat the negative regions as a separate area? I did not know this.

Answer (score 2):

The yellow part plus the blue part is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{\pi }{3}}^{\frac{5 \pi }{3}} (\cos (t)+1)^2 \, dt= \pi -\frac{9}{8}  \sqrt{3}$$

The blue part is twice the circle sector of $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ that is one third of the circle less twice the equilateral triangle having side $1.5$

$\dfrac{1}{3} \pi  \left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3} }{4} \left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^2\right)=\dfrac{3 \pi }{4}-\dfrac{9}{8} \sqrt{3}$

The requested area is therefore

$$\pi -\frac{9}{8}  \sqrt{3}-\left(\dfrac{3 \pi }{4}-\dfrac{9}{8} \sqrt{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

[image]